# Apache2 document root in /home/ folder - permissions

Tags: permissions, apache2

Since a while ago I decided to say goodbye to Windows and start my journey in Linux. So far everything has been great. but when it comes to the permissions I am a little overwhelmed.

I am running a LAMP Stack with multiple CraftCMS installations. Everything works fine, but I am unable to execute CraftCMS's command line tools. Because I do not have the required permissions.

I do however understand where this comes from. Let me explain my setup:

My document root is living in `/home/mike/websites/`
Due to the fact that I have my document root in my home folder and not in `/var/www/` the user that runs apache doesn't have acces to my document root.
I solved this by making the user `www-data` the owner of `/home/mike/websites/`. I did this by running `sudo chown -R www-data /home/mike/websites/`
The websites work fine at this point, but I don't have access myself. To fix this I added myself to the group `www-data`, with the command: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data mike`

This is the point where we are now. Almost everything works fine and I can acces everything as i should.

When trying to run `./craft` in `/home/mike/websites/websiteA/` I get an error : `bash: ./craft: Permission denied`
If I run the command with sudo permissions `sudo ./craft` I get the error : `sudo: ./craft: command not found`
The only way I can get it to work is by using `sudo php ./craft`. But that's a bit tedious.

I do however have an idea why: When I write a php command in the console it will be executed by my user. Which probably doesn't have Php permissions to this folder.

Now, How do I fix this? Or should I move my document root to `/var/www/`

What is the right way?

ls -l craft output:
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 577 apr 30 11:02 craft`

Comment: "Or should I move my document root to /var/www/" This. What you want is possible but a lot more config. Put it in /var/www/ with www-data as user and a group (www-data would be the default), add mike to that group.

Comment: What if I want my document root to be accessible easily? I love having all the websites in my /home/ folder. @Rinzwind

Comment: you can always symlink :)

Comment: Could you post "ls -l craft" output?

Comment: @Lety Sure, updated my question.

Comment: I guess you have shebang inside craft, and in your path variable there is the path to php executable. check if php is executable and who is the owner. Admin user enviroment variable probably did not have references to php path, this is why you have to use "sudo php ./craft"

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried what you said, the default `/var/www/html` folder is not owner by apache. It is a folder owner by the root user. meaning it would require some configuration to work too. I want to know the optimal way of doing this. Are you sure this is the way to do this?

Comment: @Lety Yes, it does have shebang. thank you for you explanation. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: did you check if php executable is executable and who is the owner? Could you please add ls -l <phpPath>/php

Comment: this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied could help, and probably you have not php in your PATH environment variable